# what is the correct way to implement a factory method that instantiates objects based on supplied generic object

Tags: java, generics, factory

I'm trying to find the "correct" way to create a factory that consumes generic objects of supertype-A and based on their type, it produces generic objects of supertype-B, but I think I'm getting bitten by Java's non reified generics. What would be the "true Java way" to implement something like this:

Hierarchy of fictional objects to be consumed by the factory:

```
abstract class Shape<T extends Shape> {

    private String userFriendlyShapeName = "not set";

    public abstract String getArea();
    public final String getUserFriendlyShapeName() { return userFriendlyShapeName; }
}

class Circle extends Shape<Circle> {

    public String getArea() { return ""; //return area }
    public String getCircumference() { return ""; //return circumference }
    public String getRadius() { return ""; //get radius }
}

class Square extends Shape<Square> {

    public String getArea() { return ""; //return area }
    public String getSideLength() { return ""; //return side length }
}
```

The fictional factory:

```
class DrawableShapeFactory {
    public <T extends Shape, S extends DrawableShape> DrawableShape<S> createDrawableShapeFrom(String userFriendlyDrawableShapeName, Shape<T> shape) {
        //these won't work:
        //T drawableShape = (T) shape;
        //return createDrawableShape(userFriendlyDrawableShapeName, drawableShape);
        //or 
        // return createDrawableShape(userFriendlyDrawableShapeName, (T) shape);
        return null;
    }


    private DrawableShape<DrawableCircle> createDrawableShape(String userFriendlyName, Circle circle) {
        DrawableShape<DrawableCircle> drawableShape = new DrawableCircle(userFriendlyDrawableShapeName, circle);
        return drawableShape;
    }

    private DrawableShape<DrawableSquare> createDrawableShape(String userFriendlyName, Square square) {
        DrawableShape<DrawableSquare> drawableShape = new DrawableSquare(userFriendlyDrawableShapeName, square);
    }
}
```

In this scenario there is a class to produce Shapes and then pass them to a fictional Drawer class as shapes, which would then instantiate an appropriate drawable shape, e.g.:

```
class ShapeCreator {
    ...
    ShapeCreator() {
        shapeDrawer.draw(someShapeCreatedEarlier);
    }
    ...
}

class ShapeDrawer() {
    ...
    public draw(Shape shape) {
       draw(drawableShapeFactory.createDrawableShapeFrom(shape));
    }

    private draw(DrawableShape<Circle> drawableShape) {
        //an implementation that draws a circle on the wall
    }

    private draw(DrawableShape<Square> drawableShape) {
        //an implementation that draws a square on the wall
    }
}
```

Apologies about the length of this post and any potential syntax issues. Any feedback (including design or anything really) is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The general type of problem that you are working with is called a double-dispatch problem. Usually, polymorphism is used so that, depending on which object a method is called, the method call behaves differently. For example:

```
public interface Shape {
    public String getSimpleName();
}

public class Circle implements Shape {

    @Override
    public String getSimpleName() {
        return "Circle";
    }
}

public class Square implements Shape {

    @Override
    public String getSimpleName() {
        return "Square";
    }
}
```

This called single-dispatch because the behavior of the `getSimpleName` method only depends on one factor--namely, the specific implementation type of the object called (i.e. `Circle` or `Square`). In double-dispatch, the behavior of the call changes depending on the object on which it is called and the argument passed to the method (hence the *double* in double-dispatch).

To solve your problem, you may be able to forego a factory entirely if you create a new interface called `Drawer` and a new method to `Shape` called `draw` that accepts a `Drawer` object. This `draw` method does nothing but defer to the supplied `Drawer` object and depending on which `Shape` the `draw` method is called on, the logic for drawing the shape will vary. This is called the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and an example of its implementation for your problem would look like the following:

```
public interface Shape {
    public void draw(Drawer drawer);
}

public interface Drawer {
    public void draw(Circle circle);
    public void draw(Square square);
}

public class Circle implements Shape {

    @Override
    public void draw(Drawer drawer) {
        drawer.draw(this);
    }
}

public class Square implements Shape {

    @Override
    public void draw(Drawer drawer) {
        drawer.draw(this);
    }
}

public class SimpleDrawer implements Drawer {

    @Override
    public void draw(Circle circle) {
        System.out.println("Drew a simple circle");
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Square square) {
        System.out.println("Drew a simple square");
    }
}

public class ComplexDrawer implements Drawer {

    @Override
    public void draw(Circle circle) {
        System.out.println("Drew a complex circle");
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Square square) {
        System.out.println("Drew a complex square");
    }
}
```

Note that you can add any other methods you want to the `Drawer` and `Shape` interfaces, but those are the minimal methods needed to implement the pattern. You can then draw shapes by doing the following:

```
Circle circle = new Circle();
SimpleDrawer drawer = new SimpleDrawer();
circle.draw(drawer);
```

This will output the following:

```
Drew a simple circle
```

Using the Visitor Pattern should remove the need for wrapping the `Shape` objects into `Drawable` objects and remove the issue with non-reified types. The catch is that when you add a new `Shape` implementation, you have to add a new `draw` method to the `Drawer` interface that accepts the new implementation as an argument. This may hinder flexibility a bit, but the benefit is that you do not need to worry about a quirky factory method to wrap your `Shape` objects.

The repeated implementation of `draw(Drawer)` is important because the type of `this` changes for each of the `Shape` implementations. In essence, the `this` argument passed to `draw` directs which `draw` method of the `Drawer` implementation is called (e.g. `draw(Circle)` or `draw(Square)`). As an additional benefit, within each `draw` method in the `Drawer` implementations, the `Shape` passed in is of its implementation type (e.g. `Circle` or `Square`) so no unsafe casting is needed: You already have the *actual* type of the object.

---

The above is the main solution, but if you only have one `Drawer` implementation--let's say `DefaultDrawer`--having to provide the `draw` method of `Shape` with a `Drawer` everytime can be a pain. To alleviate this issue, you can add a `draw()` method to the `Shape` interface and have an abstract class provide the default implementation. For example:

```
public interface Shape {
    public void draw(Drawer drawer);
    public void draw();
}

public abstract class DefaultShape implements Shape {

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        draw(new DefaultDrawer());
    }
}
```

`Shape` implementations would then extend the `DefaultShape` class and provide an implementation for `draw(Drawer drawer)`. You can then draw a shape by simply calling `draw()`, as in `circle.draw()`. The downside is now you have tied your `Shape` implementations to a specific `Drawer` (i.e. the `DefaultShape` depends on a *specific* `Drawer` rather than the general `Drawer` interface) and the `Shape` implementations now extend an abstract class rather than implement an interface.